# Proving convergence for recurring sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction, recurrence-relations

I have been trying to use induction to prove that a recurring sequence is monotone, but the problem that I'm having is that no initial values are given. Can someone please give a hint as to how to approach this?

Comment: Is there any condition on $a_0$?

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo yes, it cannot be 1,0, or -1.

Answer (score 1):

Even if $a_n$ tend to some limit $l$, the limit must satisfy the recurrence relation, i.e. $$l={l-1\over l+1}$$which leads to $l^2+l=l-1$ with no solutions in real numbers. So, your sequence is divergent.